# How can I display the FULL URL in a Web Analytics web part?

Tags: 2010, web-analytics, site-usage

When displaying "Top Pages" for a site (it is a blog showing various News stories), it seems the Querystring parameter is 'cut off' from the display.

How can I display the FULL URL including the querystring parameter in the Web Analytics web part?

An example of what is shown in the web part below:

```
/lists/posts/viewpost.aspx?... (3)
/lists/posts/viewpost.aspx?... (2)
/lists/posts/viewpost.aspx?... (2)
/lists/posts/viewpost.aspx?... (2)
/lists/posts/viewpost.aspx?... (1)
/lists/posts/viewpost.aspx?... (1)
/lists/posts/viewpost.aspx?... (1)
```

What is missing is the "ID=" portion, which is important for our client.

Comment: Have a look at this webpart on codeplex - it addresses some of the limitations of the OOB web analytics webpart. https://sp2010mostviewedpages.codeplex.com

Comment: Unfortunately it seems it only shows information from the pages library.